# Camera turns black upon resume

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, preview

My app uses multiple features for Apple's demo project AVCam. Everything works just fine except when I exit the app and go back in it, it doesn't show the camera preview anymore. Does anyone know what piece of code I am supposed to use and where it belongs? I tried searching but a lot of questions relating to android popped up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize your camera once the App becomes active again. In your app delegate methods, override, applicationDidBecomeActive and send a notification so your view controller knows that your app became active again.

Pending the notification received, you can reload the viewDidLoad, or move the contents of viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear. There's multiple ways to do this. You can also reload the contents of viewDidLoad in viewWillAppear. There's many many many ways to do this, like I said.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me some code as an example of one of your methods?

Comment: change - (void)viewDidLoad { in your view controller to - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {. See if that quick fix works.